# How can I increase the ride height of my vehicle?

Tags: suspension, buick, ride-height

2001 Buick Regal

[image]

It already has a naturally low ride height,

[image]

And I feel like I've lost some over the years. The suspension is stock with the exception of new shocks I installed about 6 months ago. In the interest of full disclosure I do have a trunk full of car audio equipment, subs and amplifiers, probably 100-150lbs, but I've taken it out at times (like when I replaced the shocks) and it didn't seem to make a lot of difference. I'm looking for a way to economically increase the ride height 1-2" if possible.

Comment: I was going to suggest something like [Air Lift air bags](https://www.airliftcompany.com/shop/60897/) but your vehicle suspension will not accept them. I used a set on my 94 Z28 when I was bottoming out on my snubbers (lowered suspension ~1.5-2"). They worked very well ... not going to work for your setup, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you know, the rear shocks are McPherson struts. There aren't a lot of options to lift a car with a suspension like that. At least not economically.

Most obvious, would be replacing the springs with new ones. This may give you some extra ride height, as the original ones are likely sagging and the progressive resistance has diminished some.

[image]

Comment: You can probably find replacements which are have a variable spring rate. That way you'd be soft on top when not loaded and more spring rate on the loaded side with the extra weight. Don't know if they are made for this model of vehicle, but they are out there.

Comment: @Paulster2 That is a great comment. I was looking for aftermarket springs with that spec, but all I could find was OEM or lowering. Would be nice to be able to find some for a towing package, etc.

Comment: While even less economical, you *can* [have them made](http://www.coilsprings.com/) if not available through normal aftermarket sources.

Comment: @CharlieRB Just throwing this out there.  You might check with some scrap yards nearby.  You never know what you might find.

Comment: @Jerreck FYI: This isn't my question. I don't need springs, I was looking for them to suggest to the OP.

Comment: Replaced the shock/spring assembly all the way around a few months back, little difference in ride height, noticeably smoother ride though, especially around the railroad tracks. Marking this as the answer b/c it looks like this is it.

Comment: New struts and Springs. It wouldn't make sense to replace Springs only if the struts are worn bad enough to make the originals sag. You can also look for a spring from a different trim level, or completely different model, as they often change spring rate to compensate for weight or to change handling characteristics. If I'm not mistaken, that Buick shares the same platform as the Pontiac Grand Prix and Olds Alero, so it's possible that one of them would have a stiffer spring from factory, esp the gran prix gt.  a stiffer spring can help if you tend to have a lot of extra weight in the trunk